# Do we have something similar/equivalent to Jdbctemplate in Python?

Tags: python, jdbctemplate

I'm looking for Jdbtemplate equivalent in Python. Any one saw something similar somewhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one, [Spring Python DatabaseTemplate](http://springpython.webfactional.com/1.2.x/sphinx/html/dao.html)